# modulo of 2 polynoms

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to understand the example given in the wikipedia explanation of the algorithm of Reed Solomon: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction.
We have

$p(x) = 3x^6 + 2x^5 + x^4$

$g(x) = x^4 + 809x^3 + 723x^2 + 568x + 522$

$s(x) = p(x) \mod g(x) = 547x^3 + 738x^2 + 442x + 522.$

I don't understand how do we calculate $s(x)$. I thought that we just have to divide $p$ by $g$, but I enormous numbers for the remainders.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The polynomials are in $GF(929)$, so you can reduce the _enormous numbers_ $\mod 929.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write $p(x) = q(x)g(x)+s(x)$ the 'normal' algorithm (i.e. working in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$) gives
$$q(x)=3 x^2-2425x+1959657$$
$$s(x)=-1583610942x^3-1415456177x^2-1111819326x-1022940954.$$
If you reduce the coefficients modulo $929$ because the example is in $GF(929)$ you get
$$q(x)=3x^2+362x+396$$
$$s(x)=547x^3+738x^2+442x+455.$$
Note the small typo (522 vs 455) in your $s(x)$ compared to wiki.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much!!